# Why the lastname comes immediately after the firstname and the firstname remains empty

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Employee "+(i+1)+" Details:");
    System.out.flush();
    System.out.println("Enter the FirstName");
    String f=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the LastName");
    String l=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Mobile");
    String m=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Email");
    String e=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Address");
    String a=sc.nextLine();
    Employee x=new Employee();
    x.setDetails(f, l, m, e, a);
    E.add(x);   
}
```

that was the loop, E is an Arraylist of class Employee. While entering the 1st employee details the firstname field remains empty. I can't understand why is it happening
[the following output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbc3G.png)

Comment: were you doing a sc.nextInt before this loop?

Comment: Change `System.out.flush();` with `sc.nextLine();`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo